# sharing Image from App to other app in ios

Tags: iphone

How to share an image from my app to other app?
I have a button in my `UIViewController` and when it is clicked it should show other app available for sharing

1. how can I show a pop up showing all the apps available?
2. how can I share it with flicker app?

Comment: objective-c or swift? are you using a storyboard?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
let activityItem: [AnyObject] = [self.imageView.image as! AnyObject]

let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItem as [AnyObject], applicationActivities: nil)

self.presentViewController(avc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: `NSArray *activityItems = @[self.imageView.image];
    
    UIActivityViewController *activityController =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
     initWithActivityItems:activityItems
     applicationActivities:nil];
  
    [self presentViewController:activityController
                       animated:YES completion:nil];`